# Update Document List from Workflow Form

Tags: workflow, document-library, task-list, approval

I have a Document Library and an approval workflow.

A user submits a document and gets reviewed by an expert. I have customized the workflow with an additional field called "Document Classification", there's only 4 choices (Class 1, Class 2, etc.).

Every time an Expert approves the document using the workflow, he/she needs to classify the document.

The classification happens on the workflow tasks only, I need the classification to  be copied on the Document Library as well.

Can you guys help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of SharePoint you are using?

Comment: I'm using SharePoint 2013